# Viewing my site in Chrome's inspector iPad view not working?

Tags: google-chrome, responsive

I'm not sure how to ask what I need to ask, so please bear with me.  I'm using Chrome to view my website in iPad mode, and I'm simultaneously viewing the site in my iPad. The changes I make to the sight are shown in Chrome but not in my iPad. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, is there any url to look that? There might be a couple of reasons. Screenshot or steps to reproduce the issue might be better to debug?